# Linux-like Ctrl-C (KeyboardInterrupt) for the Windows cmd line?

Tags: windows, terminal

I've been forced into using a command line in windows and wondered if there were Linux-like keyboard shortcuts? I googled and didn't find what I was looking for.

Things like ^C, ^Z and such?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can trap ^C on Windows with SIGINT, just like Linux. The Windows shell, such as it is, doesn't support Unix style job control (at least not in a way analogous to Unix shells), and ^Z is actually the ^D analog for Windows.

Comment: I don't know about Unix style job control, but now in Windows you have [Powershell Background Jobs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878288(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 35):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd>: some programs respond to it instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. On some keyboards <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd> translates to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Pause</kbd>.

Note also that nothing can cancel synchronous network I/O (such as `net view \\invalid`) on Windows before Vista.

Answer (score 7):

There are two keyboard combinations that can be used to stop process in Windows command line.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is the "nicer" method. Programmers can handle this in software. It's possible to write programs that ignore <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> as `SIGINT` signal completely, or handle <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> like a regular keyboard combination.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>break</kbd> is the "harder" method, always sends `SIGBREAK` signal and cannot be overridden in software.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl-C does a similar thing in windows as it does in linux.

Comment: In Linux Ctrl-C can halt many stuck processes, but it seems that my stuck windows command is Ctrl-C proof! Thanks though!

Comment: This is simply not true

Comment: @AKA which bit is the "not true" bit?