# what is shortcut command to kill process in windows command?

Tags: windows, shortcut

Problem :

I have a process in windows command which cannot be killed. I tried taskkill and all the shortcuts in this post
[Linuxlike Ctrl-C (KeyboardInterrupt) for the Windows cmd line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800521/linuxlike-ctrl-c-keyboardinterrupt-for-the-windows-cmd-line)

It refuses to die, even Windows task manager doesn't work to kill the command prompt. This program is resistant.

Comment: Something is running in command prompt and has control of the output command. I should do this opening another windows?

Comment: either kill the cmd.exe process in taskmanager, or kill it with taskill. either way, you kill it.

Comment: Usually if you want to kill all processes associated with a particular console window, the window's close button will work.  But if a process has gotten stuck in kernel mode (rare, but it happens sometimes) then there may be no option but a reboot.

Comment: Superusers have suggested https://superuser.com/questions/568906/possible-to-stop-the-current-execution-of-commands-in-command-prompt/568907#comment2309517_568907 and https://superuser.com/questions/955969/windows-10-cmd-ctrl-c-not-killing-processes/956058#comment2309515_956058, neither of which work anymore. Microsoft has changed the behavior yet again.

Answer (score 34):

Ctrl + C should stop a program running from the command prompt, similar to linux.

If that doesn't work try to force kill a process from the command prompt, using the following command:

```
taskkill /F /IM process.exe
```

/F will force termination of the process, /IM means you're going to provide the running executable that you want to end, thus process.exe is the process to end.

tried using alt + F4?

Comment: With /F I was able to kill the process. But the original Command Prompt which executed the program won't die. It's still there. Tried Task Manager and ALT + F4 to kill it

Comment: @Cher the cmd is a different program than your target process.

Comment: The spaces were essential.  & Then Ctrl alt delete task manager finally shows the 3 instances of chrome ... which gives me hope I can exit chrome and regain my computer , without switching it off.  Gosh opperation could not be completed access denied.

Answer (score 3):

I was in a similar situation where **exit()** and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> were the commands used to escape.

Typically entering *exit* (or *logout*) will provide you with assisting information, in my case I had the following output:

> Use exit() or Ctrl-Z plus Return to exit

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is only for Python.

Answer (score 0):

**In Windows:**

First try: `Ctrl + C` If it doesn't work then try pressing `q`

**In MAC OS:**

Press `Cmd + C` or `Ctrl + C` or `q`