# Why does ctrl + c not stop tornado server?

Tags: tornado

Why does <kbd>ctrl + c</kbd> not stop tornado server on windows ?

This code is not executed: `print 'get sig:%d' % signum`

```
import signal

import tornado
import tornado.web
import tornado.httpserver


class DefaultHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        self.set_status(200, 'OK')
        self.write('hello guest')

    def post(self):
        self.get()


class Receiver(object):

    def __init__(self, address=None, port=8100, gzip=False):

        if not address:
            address = '0.0.0.0'
        self.address = address
        self.port = port
        self.gzip = gzip
        self.http_server = None

    def start(self):
        settings = dict(
        )
        application = tornado.web.Application([
            (r"/", DefaultHandler),],
            **settings)
        self.http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application, decompress_request=self.gzip)
        self.http_server.listen(self.port)
        tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()

    def shutdown(self):

        if self.http_server is not None:
            self.http_server.stop()
        tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().stop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    receiver = Receiver(port=8901)

    def sig_handler(signum, frame):
        print 'get sig:%d' % signum
        receiver.shutdown()


    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, sig_handler)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, sig_handler)
    receiver.start()
```

**My solution:**

*only main thread can handle signal, so use thread to start receiver and let main thread do some fake work to keep alive*

```
threading.Thread(target=receiver.start).start()
while 1:
    try:
        time.sleep(2)
    except:
        break
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/800559/1925257.

Answer (score 3):

Signal handlers are a special environment. You have to be careful what you do in one because you don't know the state of the functions that were interrupted by the signal. In tornado, only *one* function is guaranteed safe to call from inside a signal handler: `IOLoop.add_callback_from_signal`. Instead of calling `shutdown()` directly, use `add_callback_from_signal` to schedule it:

```
def sig_handler(signum, frame):
    IOLoop.current().add_callback_from_signal(receiver.shutdown)
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the more detailed answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52941752/207661

In short, you need to install Ctrl+C handler for Windows manually.

Below are handy functions which will detect Windows and install custom handler for Ctrl+C in console:

```
#win_ctrl_c.py

import sys

def handler(a,b=None):
    sys.exit(1)
def install_handler():
    if sys.platform == "win32":
        import win32api
        win32api.SetConsoleCtrlHandler(handler, True)
```

You can use above like this:

```
import threading
import time
import win_ctrl_c

# do something that will block
def work():
    time.sleep(10000)        
t = threading.Thread(target=work)
t.daemon = True
t.start()

#install handler
install_handler()

# now block
t.join()

#Ctrl+C works now!
```